# Combinatorics through Recursion: How to be functional

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, julia

I am working on a combinatorics function. I want to input a string and output all possible combinations of that string using each character. For instance, this will print all the combinations of ME = {MM, ME, EM, EE}.

```
function combo_recursive(a)

  arr_combo = split(a, "")
  arr_size = size(arr_combo)
  arr_max = arr_size[1]
  mutab!e = []

  function combo_recurse(b)
    if b ≤ 1
      for i in 1:arr_max
        append!(mutab!e,arr_combo[i])
        println(join(mutab!e))
        pop!(mutab!e)
      end
    else
      for j in 1:arr_max
        append!(mutab!e,arr_combo[j])
        combo_recurse(b-1)
        pop!(mutab!e)
      end
    end
  end

  combo_recurse(arr_max)

end
```

It works fine but, I implemented mutable arrays to achieve the desired result. Any recommendations on how to apply a functional ethos to this??

Comment: It sounds like what you want is: every possible string from the same alphabet of the source, with the same length. You might generate every list of length N by recursively generating every list of length n-1, then concatenating the lists formed by prepending each possible character in the alphabet to the lists of length N-1.

Comment: Does this work for you? `combo(a) = join.(Iterators.product((Iterators.repeated(collect(a),length(a)))...))`

Comment: Davislor - Yes, its the definition of "permutation with repetition". The recursion was a method of achieving the output.

Comment: Bogumil - Wow, that is excellent. Thanks! Now I'm off to familiarize myself with the Iterators.